# How to find if a graph is a tree and its center

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, parent-child

Is there an algorithm (or a sequence of algorithms) to find, given a generic graph structure `G=(V,E)` with no notion of *parent node, leaf node and child node* but only neighboordhood relations:

1) If `G` it is a tree or not (is it sufficient to check `|V| = |E|+1`?)

2) If the graph is actually a tree, the leaves and the center of it? (i.e the node of the graph which minimizes the tree depth)

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the "center" of the tree is defined as "the node of the graph which minimizes the tree depth", there's an easier way to find it than finding the diameter.

```
d[] = degrees of all nodes
que = { leaves, i.e  i that d[i]==1}
while len(que) > 1:
  i=que.pop_front
  d[i]--
  for j in neighbors[i]:
    if d[j] > 0:
      d[j]--
      if d[j] == 1 :
        que.push_back(j)
```

and the last one left in que is the center.

you can prove this by thinking about the diameter path.
to simpify , we assume the length of the diameter path is odd, so that the middle node of the path is unique, let's call that node M,

we can see that:

1. M will not be pushed to the back of que until every node else on
   diameter path has been pushed into que
2. if there's another node N
   that is pushed after M has already been pushed into que, then N must
   be on a longer path than the diameter path. Therefore N can't exist. M must be the last
   node pushed (and left) in que

Comment: Your algorithm is what I was trying to figure out! I've implemented it in c++ using std::list as the queue

Comment: How to find if more than one centers of a tree exist?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, it is not enough - a tree is a CONNECTED graph with `n-1` edges. There could be `n-1` edges in a not connected graph - and it won't be a tree.

   You can run a [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to find if the graph is connected and then count the number of edges, that will give you enough information if the graph is a tree
2. The leaves are the nodes `v` with degree of the nodes denoted by `d(v)` given by the equation `d(v) = 1` (which have only one connected vertex to each)

---

(1) The answer assumes non-directed graphs

(2) In here, `n` denotes the number of vertices.

Answer (score 2):

For (1), all you have to do is verify |V| = |E| + 1 and that the graph is fully connected.

For (2), you need to find a maximal diameter then pick a node in the middle of the diameter path.  I vaguely remember that there's an easy way to do this for trees.

You start with an arbitrary node `a`, then find a node at maximal distance from `a`, call it `b`.  Then you search from `b` and find a node at maximal distance from `b`, call it `c`.  The path from `b` to `c` is a maximal diameter.

There are other ways to do it that might be more convenient for you, like [this one](http://tech-queries.blogspot.com/2010/09/diameter-of-tree-in-on.html).  [Check Google too](https://www.google.com/search?q=find+maximal+diameter+of+a+tree+graph).